# CAP Theorem - What are the reasons for partitioning in first place?

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, cap-theorem

There are plenty of good stackoverflow Q&A on the CAP theorem as CP vs AP etc.

In a nutshell the theorem states:

> "In the presence of a partition you must sacrifice availability or consistency"

Lets imagine we speak about storage, databases in particular.

#### What are the **technical** reasons to Partition in first place?

(I'll try to take some guesses below):

- OS can handle only so many ports/system handles.
- Single "N Petabyte" Hard discs do not exist, you need more, until you run out of SATA/PCI ports.
- Bringing the data closer to the consumer.
- Single Database size is limited to size X.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there is a difference in meaning between "partitioning" as per CAP and "partitioning" as per physical database design.

"partitioning" as per CAP refers to what happens when a node in a distributed system becomes unavailable/unreachable, thus refers to phenomena that happen "at run time".

"partitioning" as per physical database design refers to the design decision to distribute the physical records representing the rows of one single table across various distinct physical stores, but 'distinct' might even then still mean only 'various distinct segments of one single store'.  Anyhow, it thus refers to things that happen at design time.

In particular, it means that if you do "partitioning" as per physical database design, this does not necessarily lead to the existence of a "distributed system" in the sense of CAP.  In particular, when "partitioning" as per physical database design, you do not necessarily create a system with various distinct runtime components operating "independently" : if you partition a table, you'll still typically have only one single DBMS that you are communicating with, thus only one sole runtime component.

Also in particular, if you "partition" as per physical database design, it is wrong to conclude that because of CAP theorem, consistency must necessarily have been sacrificed.